# Make 2 writers spring batch transactional

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How to make transactional 2 writers - one JDBC writer and a flat file writer?

When for example the directory to write in doesn't exist I have a `fileNotFoundException`. But the other JDBC writer already wrote in database.

I tried `@Transactional` in the writer, but the exception occurred in the compressor.

Comment: I guess you need a CompositeItemWriter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `CompositeItemWriter` with two item writers. The transaction will be around the composite writer, so if one of the delegates fails the transaction will be rolled back and the other delegate's operation will be reverted as well.

In your case, a failure in writing the file will make the database insertion to be reverted due to the rollback of the transaction.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is in another step that compress what wrote in zip file, when an error is occured, there is no way to rollback, i find a proposition : to delete the writed records in tha block catch of the exception, but i feel there is better manner to do